# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar error

Tags: java-8, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

My Java project written and compiled in 1.8 through Maven. I am getting the following error when I try to analyze my code using sonar-maven-plugin Ver. 3.9.1.2184 for SonarQube 9.2.4.

The following parameters are mentioned.

sonar.java.jdkHome=D:....\jdk1.8.0_121
sonar.java.source=1.8

Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/../.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.1.2184/sonar-maven-plugin-3.9.1.2184.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/../.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

Answer (score 2):

See https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/ for Java Class File versions.

Your error tells you, that you are using JDK 8 (52.0) but the plugin code was compiled with JDK 11 (55.0). So your JDK is unable to understand the plugin classes.

What to do? Change the JDK with which you execute the maven build to JDK 11. Your source code can still be java 8 and you can also compile for jdk8 - but the excuting JDK must be 11+.

Comment: What steps to perform for suggested solution on Intellij IDEA 2022.2.3 CE (IDE)?

Comment: What steps to perform for suggested solution on Intellij IDEA 2022.2.3 CE (IDE)?

Our solution was:
`<plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId><version>3.8.1</version><configuration><verbose>true</verbose><fork>true</fork><!-- source: compiles on a JDK with the specified version --><source>8</source><compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion><!-- target: runs on a JRE with the specified version --><target>11</target><executable>${JAVA_HOME_11}/bin/javac</executable></configuration></plugin>`

Answer (score 0):

You can go through below command to archive your issue. I was facing the same but below command worked to resolve.

`- mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:Port -Dsonar.login=Token -Dsonar.login=Sonar_username -Dsonar.password=Sonar_password`

Comment: Why do you have duplicate params for "sonar.login"? One is set to "Token" and the other set to "Sonar_username".

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube above 9.0 requires java 11.

Comment: Java 11 is only required for running Sonarqube itself and the dependent maven-plugin. But Java 11 is NOT required for the Java-Code to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be caused by Java 8 version of Jacoco using a Java 11 version of Sonar. In that case Jacoco version will also need to be upgraded to Java 11 version. I upgraded Jacoco from 0.7.8 to 0.8.8 and the problem was fixed.